# Encrypt then checksum or vice versa?

Tags: encryption

This is probably a naive question, but here goes: What is better for security over TCP/IP?

1. Encrypting the payload and then adding a checksum?
2. Checksuming the payload and then encrypting it?
3. Checksuming the payload and then encrypting it, then checksuming again?
4. Something else entirely?

And by security, I mean bad guys can't read the payload, replay the messages, inject their own messages, or modify the messages in transit without detection.

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one answer correct, as all the answers were very helpful. @Terry Chia's link ended up being the most informative to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean using a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) when you say checksum.

The ideal situation is encrypt-then-MAC. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) question for more information why.

Answer (score 7):

For the **practical** answer, what's best for security is *to avoid reinventing the wheel*. Designing a secure protocol for data transport is a daunting task (it's easy to make it work, it is hard to know whether it is "secure"). There are already a few known protocols which have been studied a lot, and are available as ready to use library. Foremost of which is [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246). You might want to use [DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347) if you want to protect individual packets (DTLS is to UDP what TLS is to TCP).

For the **scientific** answer: when it comes to encrypting some data *and* protecting its integrity, best idea is to use an encryption mode which does both ([GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) and [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) are the usual suggestions). If you have to rely on separate algorithms for the encryption and for the integrity check (what you apparently call a "checksum" but is better known as a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)), then the correct way is to encrypt first, *then* compute the MAC on the encrypted data (not forgetting the IV and some other stuff, as explained in this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)).

But let me point out that this is only part of the protocol. Doing encryption and a MAC on a "payload" assumes that sender and receiver already share a common high-entropy secret value which they can use as key for the encryption and MAC. You also need some more features to avoid [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), and, more generally, defeat attackers who would try to drop packets, duplicate packets, and reorder packets. *Authentication* (one-way or mutual) is yet another tricky area.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are reinventing "Tunnel mode ESP" (which is the only useful protocol in IPSec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec)

It encrypts then signs.